# Iterating through values from CSV and concatenating them with timestamp

Tags: function, powershell, csv, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate value imported from CSV with a timestamp (to create a filename).

It seems that when I try to use foreach with the $csv it loops through all values within one iteration.

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\servers.csv
function LogTime {return Get-Date -Format "yyyymmdd_HHmmss"}

foreach ($server in $csv)
{
$filename = $(LogTime) + "_" + $csv.SERVERNAME + ".log"
$filename
}
```

This results in.

```
20191024_091007_server1 server2.log
20191024_091007_server1 server2.log
```

What I'm looking for:

```
20191024_091007_server1.log
20191024_091007_server2.log
```

Comment: $server.ServerName

Comment: I'd use the [-f format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) to build the string `$filename = "{0}_{1}.log" -f $LogTime,$server.SERVERNAME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreach loop is not using the `$server` variable

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\servers.csv
function LogTime {return Get-Date -Format "yyyymmdd_HHmmss"}

foreach ($server in $csv)
{
    $filename = $(LogTime) + "_" + $server.SERVERNAME + ".log"
    $filename
}
```